# Hide Fields Based on dropdown value in Magnolia content app

Tags: ajax, magnolia

I am developing a content app similar to Tours. In this I have a form that has multiple fields.
Now i have a requirement like http://jsfiddle.net/5SArB/1911/ fiddle.
 I need to hide few fields based on the selection from dropdown like how parent details hidden when age is more than 18 . 
How to achieve this in magnolia content app?`enter code here`

Comment: I don't think it is possible right now. There are no "dependent" Fields in Magnolia. The only thing I can imagine you can do, is to override the Save action of your form, and validate the dependencies there.

Comment: @Rajashekhar Please, can you explain your answer that how to achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

This should be your yaml in Magnolia 5.7.

You should use the **switchable** field combined with **composite** field:

```
wide: true
form:
  tabs:
    - name: tabForm
      label: Form registration
      fields:
        - name: username
          label: Name
          fieldType: text
        - name: email
          label: Email
          fieldType: text
        - name: ageConfig
          fieldType: switchable
          label: Age
          selectionType: select
          transformerClass: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.transformer.composite.DelegatingCompositeFieldTransformer
          type: String
          options:
            - name: young
              label: 18 or younger
              value: young
            - name: old
              label: 19 or older
              value: old
          fields:
            - name: young
              fieldType: composite
              label: ''
              layout: vertical
              fields:
                - name: parentName
                  fieldType: text
                  label: Parent name
                - name: parentMail
                  fieldType: text
                  label: Parent email
            - name: old
              fieldType: hidden

actions: !include:/my-project/dialogs-common/actions-block.yaml
```

This is the "young" case:

[image: Young case]

This is the "old" case:

[image: Old case]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by extending either `SwitchableFieldFactory` or `CompositeFieldFactory` and coding desired behaviour there.

HTH,
Jan

Comment: thanks for reply, but is to possible to use select box instead of radio buttons of SwitchableFieldFacroty?

Comment: Sure just use different Factory class, there's one for each type of field.

Comment: Yes, I am able to achieve this, but not able to save. I have reported this magnolia bug at https://jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/MGNLUI-3533

Comment: Please can you post the code and explain how to achieve this?

Comment: @Jan and  Please, can you explain your answer that how to achieve it?

Comment: @Rajashekhar Please, can you explain your answer that how to achieve it?