# Show/Hide different fields Based on dropdown value in Magnolia content app?

Tags: content-management-system, magnolia

I have created a content app in which I am able to show and hide different fields using radio buttons but how to Show/Hide different fields Based on the dropdown value in Magnolia content app?

For radio button and fields i used below class `info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.SwitchableFieldDefinition`
and for transformer class i used
  `info.magnolia.ui.form.field.transformer.composite.DelegatingCompositeFieldTransformer`

but now i want to use

```
info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.SelectFieldDefinition
```

instead of `SwitchableFieldDefinition`but I am unable to do so with any of the transformer class.

I also searched and found similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066415/hide-fields-based-on-dropdown-value-in-magnolia-content-app) but it has the incomplete answer!

Answer (score 0):

According to https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Switchable+field you can define a property named "selectionType" with the value "select".
I haven't tested that though.
If you have a look in SwitchableFieldDefinition, it looks promising though, because there's really a property with that name and it just defaults to "radio" but can be overwritten.