# How to dynamically change dialog with select field

Tags: content-management-system, components, freemarker, magnolia

I'm new to Magnolia, and I'm making my own module.
I have a dialog box when adding a component and I want to change next fields below dynamically using a select field.

Example:

Select field with {"type 1", "type 2", ...}

IF "type 1" is selected

->show a text field below

ELSE

->show a basicUpload field below

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe same was already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066415/hide-fields-based-on-dropdown-value-in-magnolia-content-app) and few other places if you look over questions tagged "magnolia".

Long story short, fields are atomic, independent entities. They do not know about each other. So the only way to create such dynamic connection is over "parent" form. You need to extend form presenter and field factory (if you want select that would be `SelectFieldFactory`) and in there, when field is created, attach value changed or similar listener to it so when value is changed in the field, you can inform presenter to make some other field visible or hide it.

IIRC you can see example of that done in External Forms module (if you have access to enterprise code). Not sure if any of the community modules show the same.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Jan, like I said, I'm new in this Magnolia world. I'm using Magnolia CE with Blossom module.
At the moment this is what I'm trying to do:   
`        tab.fields(
                cfg.fields.switchable("message").options(
                    ob.label("opt1").value("test1").selected(),
                    ob.label("opt2").value("test2")
                ).fields(
                    cfg.fields.text("test1").label("text").rows(5),
                    cfg.fields.richText("test2").label("rich")
                ).label("Message")
)`